# Automate command line from an HTML button

Tags: jquery, video, ffmpeg, phantomjs

**Info**

I am working on a native project where I try to render a HTML animation into a video.
I am currently using programs like *PhantomJS* and *FFmpeg* to get the video out of the HTML animation using command lines. I follow a tutorial as seen in the link below:

http://mindthecode.com/recording-a-website-with-phantomjs-and-ffmpeg

**Question**

I would like to have a button which triggers the command line execution.

Is it possible to make a HTML onClick button which refers to a jQuery code, and this code will then initiate a .sh or .bat file that will run the Command Line:

```
phantomjs runner.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 25 -t 10  -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart dragon.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. Basically all server technologies provide some kind of `exec` function/method to run arbitrary commands like yours. You can't do this in the browser, though. The browser doesn't have such an `exec` command and it would be a big vulnerability to run arbitrary commands from the browser.

You will have to make a request to the backend which then runs the command you want.